Codeigniter 3 edit and delete user details from database by admin role
I am creating a web application using codeigniter 3. I have created the database and views and models for user and for admin also now i stucked at some point where i need to give permission to admin so that he can delete a user information or can update it. How to do this.
Here is my edit controller view and model code respectively
//#### User Edit Controller
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class UserEditController extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('User_model'); // Correct model loading
        $this->load->helper('url'); // Load the URL helper
        $this->load->library('form_validation'); // Load form validation library
    }

    // Display the edit form with user details
    public function edit_user($userid) {
        $data['user'] = $this->User_model->get_user_by_userid($userid); // Get user data based on userid
        if (!$data['user']) {
            show_404(); // Show 404 if user not found
        }
        $this->load->view('update_user', $data); // Load view with user data
    }

    // Update user details in the database
    public function update_user($userid) {
        // Set form validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('userid', 'User ID', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('role', 'Role', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            // Validation failed, reload the edit form with existing data
            $this->edit_user($userid);
        } else {
            // Prepare user data for update
            $user_data = array(
                'userid'   => $this->input->post('userid'),
                'role'     => $this->input->post('role'),
                'password' => $this->input->post('password')
            );

            // Update user in the database
            $this->User_model->update_user_by_userid($userid, $user_data);

            // Redirect back to the edit page for further updates
            redirect('UserEditController/edit_user/' . $userid);
        }
    }

}

//#### User Edit View
<div class="container mt-5">
    <h2>Edit User Information</h2>
    <form action="<?php echo site_url('UserEditController/update_user/' . $user->userid); ?>" method="POST">
        
        <!-- User ID (Disabled, as it shouldn't be editable) -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="userid">User ID</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userid" name="userid" value="<?php echo set_value('userid', $user->userid); ?>" readonly>
        </div>

        <!-- Role -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="role">Role</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="role" name="role" required>
                <option value="">Select Role</option>
                <option value="admin" <?php echo set_select('role', 'admin', ($user->role == 'admin')); ?>>ADMIN</option>
                <option value="user" <?php echo set_select('role', 'user', ($user->role == 'user')); ?>>USER</option>
            </select>
            <?php echo form_error('role'); ?>
        </div>

        <!-- Password -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" required>
            <?php echo form_error('password'); ?>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Submit Button -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                <i class="fas fa-save"></i> Update User
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

//#### User Edit Model
<?php

class User_model extends CI_Model {

    // Insert new user into the users table
    public function insert_user($data) {
        $this->db->insert('users', $data);

        $data = $this->input->post();

    }

    public function get_user_by_userid($userid) {
        $this->db->where('userid', $userid);
        $query = $this->db->get('users'); // Replace 'users' with your table name
        return $query->row(); // Return a single row
    }

    // Update user details
    public function update_user_by_userid($userid, $user_data) {
        $this->db->where('userid', $userid);
        return $this->db->update('users', $user_data); // Replace 'users' with your table name
    }
}
?>

Ib have placed it in the user model

Before you call the update/delete action, check the permission-checking function/middleware. If you're maintaining the permission in the table, (recommended way) then align it with it

DIdn't understand
